# Error: calling a salesforce webservice using an external tool

Tags: rest-api, integration

I need to call a REST web service in salesforce from an external tool. I used a chrome add-on Rest client to call the web service in salesforce. But I am getting the following error: 
[
  {
    "message": "Session expired or invalid",
    "errorCode": "INVALID_SESSION_ID"
  }
]

These are the headers I provided:

Content-Type :  application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept : application/json
Authorization : OAuth

Comment: What external tool are you using?

Comment: I am not specific- I am doing this as a part of some testing. Which is a good tool to do this?

Comment: Chrome extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US

Comment: @gsanthan I use the [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) Chrome extension to call both the native Salesforce REST APIs and custom REST web services defined in Apex. Do you just want to see an example of this?

Comment: I just tried the tool- I am getting the [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}] error- (I have added the Authorization to the header)

Answer (score 2):

There are several documents available for you to start looking into this.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest.htm

As well as a Trailhead module:

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/apex_integration_services

Comment: I already have a REST webservice class  in my salesforce. I want to call this from an external tool other than using workbench or curl.